# How to change a css element based on other element

Tags: jquery, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t280ena2/1/) gives you the idea

```
<div class="change" style="width:150px;">xyz</div>
<div class="change" style="width:350px;z-index:999">XYZ</div>
```

I have two divs of same class in which inline css differs and i want to add one of the element z-index in 1st div as z-index:99, without directly adding it to inline css and cannot add a new class to that div as i dont have any control on them, as both divs i am getting are through jquery and cannot be edited from my end

based on the inline css width of that particular class can i add new inline-css element through jquery or any other better possible solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.change').first().css({'z-index':99,'color':'red'});`, put the `'color':'red'` just for demo https://jsfiddle.net/t280ena2/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for first one

```
jQuery('.change').first().css('z-index',1000);
```

or

```
jQuery('.change:first-child').css('z-index',1000);
```

for last one

```
jQuery('.change').last().css('z-index',1000);
```

for n-th child

```
jQuery( ".change:nth-child(n)").css('z-index',1000);
```

https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/

Comment: why do you have 2 first child methods `jQuery('.change:first-child').first()` what would that select?

Answer (score 1):

its very simple ..add below css in `head` in `<style> </style>`

```
.change:first-child{
  z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: You have to assume in this case that the .change element you want is always first.

Answer (score 0):

You can with jquery

```
var w = $('.change:first').width();
$('.change:last').css('width', w + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this :

```
$(".change").each(function(){
    if($(this).css("width") == "150px"){
    $(this).css("z-index",99);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target the exact inline property with pure CSS:

```
.change[style*='width:150px'] { z-index:99; }
```

Be as specific as you want with the property, if it ever changes this will break. If it matches another element it will apply the style there too.

Answer (score 0):

What about this, you can filter by the width of items with the `change` class:

```

```
$( ".change" ).filter(function( index ) {
    return $(this).width() === 150;
}).css( "z-index", 99 );
```

```